# How to use limits and nolimits together?

Tags: syntax

In some case limits and nolimits need to be used together, e.g. an expression `\prod\nolimits^{B}\limits_{x \in X}`, in which `B` is in the right-upper corner and `x \in X` under the `\prod`, is not displayed it should be, `B` is displayed above the `\prod`, not in the right-upper corner. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides `\sideset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\sideset{}{^{B}}\prod_{x \in X}A_{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to define your own command:

```
\newcommand{\prodB}{\sideset{}{^{B}}\prod}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
{\prod_{\mathclap{x \in X}}}^{B}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\mathclap` may give undesirable spacing when the subscript is large.

Comment: @Aditya true (it hides the size of the subscript)  although if you don't do anything it pushes B to the right if the subscript is wider than the base. sideset as in egregs answer is another possibility.

Comment: You can use `\smashoperator{\prod_{x \in X}}` instead of that `mathclap`.