# Using \limits in a customized \overset for superscript together with \sideset for subscript

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, subscripts, stacking-symbols

I am trying to create a notation for a certain space. I am using a customized `\overset` in [mrf's answer in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66723/nudging-overset-characters-downwards) to suppress the extra vertical space. I still want the subscript on the right side, so I thought `\sideset` might come in handy since I used it before as in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106219/how-to-use-limits-and-nolimits-together). The `\overset` is redefined as follows in this example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\overset}[2]{%
\mathop{#2}\limits^{\vbox to -.1ex{%
\kern -0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\vss}}}

\begin{document}
$$
\sideset{}{_0}\overset{\circ}{\mathbf{H}}(\mathbf{curl};\Omega)
$$
\end{document}
```

But unfortunately LaTeX gave me an error:

`Argument of \overset has an extra } \sideset{}{_0}\overset`.

A compromise can be adding the subscript inside `\overset` by `\overset{\circ}{\mathbf{H}_0}(\mathbf{curl};\Omega)`, the horizontal alignment of `\circ` is now to the whole `\mathbf{H}_0` and not to `\mathbf{H}`.

I have tried the `amsmath` built-in `\overset` in this example after `\sideset` and LaTeX stil gives error. I wonder if there is solution that accommodates both.

Comment: is there a reason that a simple subscript on the embellished `H` isn't acceptable, as in `{\overset{\circ}{{}\mathbf{H}}}_0(\mathbf{curl};\Omega)` ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks Barbara, it turns out it is so simple, and this is what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing `\sideset` which can only be applied to big operators such as `\sum`.  Instead just enclose the construction with the circled H in a group and add a subscript to that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\overset}[2]{%
\mathop{#2}\limits^{\vbox to -.1ex{%
\kern -0.4ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\vss}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
{\overset{\circ}{\mathbf{H}}}_0(\mathbf{curl};\Omega)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

As Barbara Beeton points out, your code results in the circled H being vertically centered.  If that is not desired then you should add an empty group before the `\mathbb{H}`:

[image: Second sample]

```
{\overset{\circ}{{}\mathbf{H}}}_0(\mathbf{curl};\Omega)
```

This is caused by a percularity/design feature of `\mathop`, which vertically centers a single symbol, but not multiple ones.

Comment: is the "circled `H`" really supposed to be vertically centered?